# Cordova Local Notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, localnotification

Hi I am developing a program. I integrated local notification to program, but problem is that i cant do it repeatly everyday .

[plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples)

I used this plugin and wrote this code in index.js in device ready. it is working normally but when i add first time for notification it gives error.

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,           
        text: "Come and Evaluate your Friends!",
        firstAt: tomorrow_at_11_am,
        every: "day"
    });
```

firstAt: tomorrow_at_11_am part is not working. How can i fix this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tomorrow_at_11_am

is a variable. The example site is missing this. Have a look at the docs here:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling

There you can find:

> at, firstAt (Date or Number)
>
> The date and time when the system should deliver the local
>   notification. If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past,
>   the local notification is delivered immediately.
>   - Default: now ~ new Date()

Comment: Thanks...  Solved it with your info :)