# cordova local notification repeat weekly

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uilocalnotification, ngcordova

I used cordova to show notification at 9:45' every monday.

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
id: 1,
title: tip.title
text: tip.content
firstAt: "monday_at_9_45_am",
every: "week",
sound: "file://sounds/reminder.mp3",
icon: "http://icons.com/?cal_id=1",
data: { meetingId:"123#fg8" }
});
```

**But why it shows error [firstAt: "monday_at_9_45_am"].**

Comment: `firstAt` takes Date object not string! So remove double quotes in `monday_at_9_45_am`.

Comment: Have a look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869998/cordova-local-notification/34870415#34870415

Comment: try this  `firstAt: monday_9_am`